# How can I pass the contents of a list to a varargs method?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I have a method that uses the varargs feature:

```
void add(Animal ...);
```

Now, instead of doing `.add(dog, cat)`, I have an Animal list with unknown number of elements,

```
List<Animal> i = new ArrayList<Animal>();
i.add(dog);
i.add(cat);
```

and want to call add with the elements of this list.

I think I could use an array, but when I do `.add(i.toArray())`, it gives a compiler error.

What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: I can't understand the question. You made your own method ´add(Animal...)´ but you are calling ArrayList.add(Object) and not your own. Why is that? Please, edit the question with the context of the code. Is that block of code inside your ´add´ method? If your only problem is that you can't cast Object[] to Animal[] then follow @Tom answer.

Comment: Just a note for the future: If you have a compiler error, please copy the complete error message, and also the source code lines relevant to this message.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's:

```
add(i.toArray(new Animal[i.size()]))
```

[List.toArray](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29) returns an `Object[]`, regardless of the type argument on the List: even though you might write `new List<String>().toArray()`, you will get an `Object[]`. However, the [version of toArray that takes an array to fill](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) returns an array with the correct type: if you write `new List<String>().toArray(new String[0])`, you will get an `String[]`. Note that the size of the array you pass in doesn't even have to match the size of the list, although it's good practice to ensure that it does.

This is ultimately due to a mildly tricky feature of generics. At first glance, you might think that `String[]` and `List<String>`mean similar things for their base types - one is an array of strings, the other is a list of strings.

However, they are in fact very different.

An array is a language primitive, and has its type baked into it. If you took a hex editor and looked at an array instance in memory in the JVM, you would be able to find (somewhere nearby) a record of the type of objects it holds. That means that if you take an instance of an array of some unknown component type, you can [find out what that type is](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType%28%29). Conversely, it means that if you're going to [create an instance of an array](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29), you need to know what component type you want.

The `List`, on the other hand, uses generics, which in Java is implemented with [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), which means that, roughly speaking, it is something that exists in the compiler, but not at runtime (the compiler can check that you get it right, but the JVM can't). This leads to a simple and efficient implementation (one simple enough to have been added to pre-generics Java without changing the JVM), but it has some shortcomings - in particular, that at runtime, there is no way to tell what the type argument on any particular instance of a generic class is, because type arguments only exist in the compiler. Because it is up to the `List` instance to handle `toArray()`, the only thing it can do is create an `Object[]`. It just doesn't know of a more specific type to use.

One way of looking at this is that arrays have a type argument as part of their *class*, whereas `List`s have a type argument as part of their *type*, and since objects have classes but variables have types, you can't get the type argument of a `List` from an object, only from a variable holding an object (as an aside, you also can't get the type argument of an array from a variable holding an array (consider `Object[] array = new String[0];`), but that doesn't really matter because, the variable lets you get hold of an object - unless it's null).

To boil this down to code, the problem is:

```
public <E> E[] createSimilarlyTypedArray(List<E> list) {
    Class<E> componentType = list.???; // there is no way to do this
    return Arrays.newInstance(componentType, list.size());
}
```

Comment: It will use your array if it is big enough or allocate a new one if it isn't.

Comment: wont you get an typecast exception when you call i.toArray(new Animal[]) on a List that doesnt have a generic type set?

Comment: @Benjamin: no, you won't. Try running `Arrays.<Object>asList("hello").toArray(new String[1]);` - it works perfectly. Statically, this is fine because that version of `toArray` picks its type parameter up from its parameter, not the owning `List` (weird but correct!), and dynamically, it's fine because at runtime, the `List`'s type has been erased.

Answer (score 0):

> when I do .add(i.toArray()) it gives an error, what is the proper way
>   to do it?

Use `foo.addAll(i)` and then convert foo to an array if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `void add(Animal...)` expects a object of the `Animal` class or a  array with Animal objects in it. You give it an array with objects of the `Object` class. Give the List a generic type like so:

```
List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
animals.add(dog);
animals.add(cat)
```

Then parse the list as argument, while converting it to an array, to your method like so:

```
add(animals.toArray(new Animal[animals.size()]);
```

More on generics can be found in the Java API

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html

Comment: More than expecting "an array with `Animal` objects in it", it expects an array whose own type is `Animal[]`. The zero-argument form of `toArray` creates an array with `Animal` objects in it - an array that is basically `new Object[] {new Animal()}`. However, what is needed is  `new Animal[] {new Animal()}`. The confluence between arrays and generics is a really treacherous patch of water!